# (()=>{})(); in PhpStorm parses as error in code

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

`(()=>{})();` in PhpStorm(2016.2) parses as error in code.

Anybody knows any quick workaround?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The IDE says syntax error. Code is alright. I'm looking for some workaround with the IDE to parse it as correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that **JavaScript Language Version** is set to `'ECMAScript 6'` in  `Settings(Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`